# duplicating column header from query in a DGV C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullpointerexception

I'm running into an issue and I'm looking for the best way to solve it. I am programming a workflow management program and I am stuck on a certain part. Essentially what I have is this. I can query all the products, and display them in a DGV(in the Product Search Class. Once they click the a checkbox and then hit a selected button all the products get transferred over to a different DGV in a different class(Quotes class). All this works fine.
The problem I'm having is that if they want to go back and select another item once it transfers to the Quotes class the column headers get duplicated. TO get around this I am trying copy what rows I have(in the quotes class DGV) into a list. I then also want to add the new selected item to the list and then set that list to my data source.
I have it copying all the info(I can display the values as it copies the cell values over to the list) it just wont display the values in the DGV, but the correct amount of rows do appear(gives a null reference error when I try to get the cell value

First is there a better way to do this?
Second is there a way to make this work?
I'll post my code.

DataGridView targetGrid = this.Q_MatDGV;
List AddRows;

```
        if (material.RowSelected)
        {
            //Checks to see if there are any rows in the material DGV already.
            if (Q_MatDGV.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                //TODO: Make it so if you have to add a new item then the column headers don't get added again.
                //I think you need to make a new array list then rebind the DGV after it's cleared out. 
                // Loop through the info that is already in the table and then you will have to get the data from the material.sourcegrid.columns and add that to the array list
                // once that is done we can then re link the dataset to the old DGV. 

                var source = new BindingSource();
                sourceGrid = this.Q_MatDGV; ;
                AddRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

               

                foreach (DataGridViewRow sourceRow in sourceGrid.Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(sourceRow.Cells["CheckBox"].Value) == true)
                    {
                        if (!sourceRow.IsNewRow)
                        {
                            var targetRow = (DataGridViewRow)sourceRow.Clone();

                            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in sourceRow.Cells)
                            {
                                targetRow.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                               // MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
                            }
                            AddRows.Add(targetRow);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach(DataGridViewRow row in material.SourceGrid.Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["CheckBox"].Value) == true)
                    {
                        AddRows.Add((DataGridViewRow)row.Clone());
                     
                    }
                }



                source.DataSource = AddRows;
               // Q_MatDGV.DataSource = null;
               // Q_MatDGV.Rows.Clear();
                Q_MatDGV.DataSource = source;
                MessageBox.Show(Q_MatDGV.Rows.Count.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(Q_MatDGV.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Better way is using `BindingList<T>` as `DataSource` and never interact with DGV for data operations. What the code is doing? Where's the data Model? What DGV contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a better way. Make a brand new project and paste this over the top of the Form1 constructor

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Chosen", typeof(bool));
        dt.Rows.Add("Matthew", true);
        dt.Rows.Add("Mark", false);
        dt.Rows.Add("Luke", false);
        dt.Rows.Add("John", false);

        var nonChosenDV = new DataView(dt);
        nonChosenDV.RowFilter = "[Chosen] = false";

        var chosenDV = new DataView(dt);
        chosenDV.RowFilter = "[Chosen] = true";

        var nonChosenDgv = new DataGridView();
        nonChosenDgv.DataSource = nonChosenDV;

        var chosenDgv = new DataGridView();
        chosenDgv.DataSource = chosenDV;


        var chosenF = new Form();
        chosenF.Text = "Only the chosen ones";
        chosenF.Controls.Add(chosenDgv);
        chosenF.Show();

        var nonChosenF = new Form();
        nonChosenF.Text = "These guys don't make the cut";
        nonChosenF.Controls.Add(nonChosenDgv);
        nonChosenF.Show();


        //add a dgv to this form to show all the data all the time
        var allDgv = new DataGridView();
        allDgv.DataSource = dt; //it will bind to the dt.DefaultView by the way
        this.Controls.Add(allDgv);
        this.Text = "All the raw data";


    }
```

Here we have some fluff to create a datatable (a model for your data to live in) that has some string/bool columns - for an easy life you should create your actual datatable in the dataset designer, but that's not so easily pastable hence why I chose the untyped route

Then we wire this same common data model up to 3 different DGV on 3 different forms, with each DGV reading the data via a different DataView that performs different filtering

Because we use a common data model, changing any of the checkboxes in any grid causes (when the row is committed by navigating to a different row) the state of affairs to update so that one grid always shows the trues, one shows the falses (and one grid shows all, and you see the ticks toggle on and off)

I did it as separate forms because you said "separate class" - there's no difference between a class and a form in this context

Object lesson is that DataGridView is NOT supposed to be something you shove your data into. You keep your data somewhere else (like a datatable) and show/interact(in a user clicks and types sense) with it via the DGV but if you want to interact with it programmatically, you get it out of the datatable, not the view (except in very particular circumstances).

If you need to do things like "access the current row" you do it via BindingSource.. The very limited circumstances where you might need to involve the DGV is for things like e.g. if the user has selected 10 rows; you get the 10 rows and ask them for their databounditem, which gives the datarow in the datatable (it gives a DataRowView, which has a .Row which is a DataRow, some casting required). You don't drag the data out via the Cell.Value

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this. If I use your example what I want to do is pull in data from my products table(out of a database) and would set that to a data table(raw data). Then from there when I wanted to select a product I could open the form select that row and it should bring that back to the main form? Am I understanding that correctly? If it works like that it does seem easier.

Comment: Additionally can I ask why it's poor practice to pull info out of the DGV instead of the DataTable?

Comment: It's kinda hard to know what problem you're actually trying to solve, but I assumed it was a classic UI trope(?) of "here are two lists, one is 'all the things you can choose' and the other is 'all the things you have chosen' and choosing something moves it from one list to the other". The example points out that you can have all your data in one place and a Boolean tracking whether it is chosen or not, and then the UI has a couple of elements that do/don't show things based on the Boolean. This makes it look like it moves from one list to the other, but it's actually only ever in one place

Comment: Whether those two lists are side by side or on different forms, one of which opens and closes (hide/show might be better, then we aren't making new things all the time) doesn't really matter, because we don't have this notion that we're going to have a grid that stores data here and another grid that stores data there and we are going to copy data from one to the other and have some complicated process of hiding data in that grid if we've already copied it to this grid. It starts to answer your second question about why we don't use windows controls to store data in directly. That's about..

Comment: ..a programming concept called MVC (not the Microsoft ASPNET product of the same name, though it implements the concept) - you have your model where your data lives, a device for viewing it (grid) and a device for controlling it (also often grid, unless the grid is made read only. Other buttons etc can control the data). Now, you *can* store data directly in the grid but it isn't very useful to do so, and makes a lot of things harder work because when everything is geared towards "data here, show there, control elsewhere", finding ways to go against it is swimming upstream. Think of it like..

Comment: .."I don't know how to edit a text file in C#, but I know how to use sendkeys. I'll sendkeys to open notepad, CTRL O and sendkeys the file path, CTRL H to open the Replace dialog, sendkeys the find/replace strings, then CTRL S to save the file". It'll work, probably, but it's ropey; it's programmatically taking the same set of actions a user would take as they click and type their way around the UI. You have access to the Model (the text file) you should edit it directly, and all the other things that are Viewing it can see the change and update, you don't need to edit the Model via Controller

Comment: like the user does, because your code has direct access to the Model. Might also be worth mentioning that not all Views of a Model actually directly represent the Model data. If you had a Textbox bound to a DateTime property of a Model, and you got the date via the .Text property you'd be getting the date as a string, and it might even be missing some parts like if it was HH:mm then you've lost the seconds when you parse it back to a DateTime - you'd just get the original DateTime out of the model.  Keep the separation of concerns clear in your mind, as it makes most things easier

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go so in depth with this. I appreciate the all the information.I will have to redo my stuff and I think this will really help. I'll let you know if I have more questions. Thank you again.